# ConstraintLayout with custom views as item in a recycler

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-constraintlayout

It seems that a `ConstraintLayout` is an improved version of a `RelativeLayout`. I was wondering, if I have custom views (let's say linear layouts but not too nested) is it a bad practice to use a `ConstraintLayout` and show these custom views positioned somewhere in the layout especially for the case of an item in a recyclerview?

Answer (score 1):

I`d say yes - when you use constrainLayout the main purpose is to keep the view hierarchy flat and avoid nested view groups.

So try **not to add** nested view groups to your constraintLayout (like relativeLayout, linear, etc...).

With constraintLayuout it is super easy to migrate your customView from linearLayout to constraintLayout and by doing so you keep your flat view hierarchy - there are not extra calculation (like in linearLayout when you use `android:weightSum` and `layout_weight`) and your layout will load faster.

Comment: 1) My question also asks about recycler view items and if they are a good fit for a constraint layout
2) By porting the custom view to the constraint layout, the file becomes much more complex. Is that a downside or not?

Comment: " By porting the custom view to the constraint layout, the file becomes much more complex. " can you explain again? because creating an XML layout for recyclerView row don't seem to be complicated. it is more easy to create than any other layout - If you can explain again i will try to answer your question

Comment: and yes recyclerView items are a good fit for constraint  layout because the creation of the layout is really simple

Comment: If I have a custom view which is a vertical LinearLayout with 2 horizontal LinearLayout as children which have 2 TextViews, I would need to have a constraintlayout with 4 TextViews extra instead of just defining the custom view. That makes the xml file more complex. That is what I meant

Comment: Well, you can manipulate your constraint layout with some guidelines and achieve your wanted result. by doing so you are NOT using nested view groups (LinearLayout withing another LinearLayout) and the result will lead to a much faster layout that needs to do less thinking to show. I disagree with you about the part when you have said that this will make your layout more complex, just create your custom view for the recyclerView  with constarintLayout - using few more constraint are better options than using multiple layouts inside one another